net::ERR INSUFFICIENT RESOURCES
1.android 13;
2.The application only contains one control, webview；
3.When the application is in the foreground and remains silent, an error is reported every 46 minutes.
4.Powered by the adapter, turn off the screen saver and keep the screen on
5.A laptop acts as a web server, a router acts as a hotspot, a tablet computer, and all devices on the LAN are configured with static IPs and no Internet connection.
enter image description here
enter image description here
log:
2024-07-01 10:45:11.959 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 10:45:11.998 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 10:45:12.257 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 11:30:38.105 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 11:30:38.149 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 12:16:01.763 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 12:16:01.803 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 12:16:03.455 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-1  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_FAILED                   webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 13:01:27.308 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 13:01:27.354 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 13:46:53.798 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 13:46:53.835 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
2024-07-01 13:46:54.068 24418-24418 ContentValues   com.example.myapplication   E  webResourceError.getErrorCode()==-15  webResourceError.getDescription()==net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  webResourceRequest.getUrl()==http:
(URL is prohibited from uploading！)
Try:
1.Register as front desk service；
2.Set to never stop screen；
3.Keep app in foreground：
4.UC Browser Long-term silence will not report such errors；
5.VIA Browser(Based on webview) Long-term silence will report this kind of error；
Expecting:
1.Does webview contain the underlying mechanism to recycle resources every 46 minutes?
2.Please help！
